# What could be the Advantage of Including Asp.net Simple Membership Tables as Part of Your Entity Framework Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I read this [blog](http://blog.spontaneouspublicity.com/including-asp-net-simple-membership-tables-as-part-of-your-entity-framework-model).

Id describes how we can include Asp.net SimpleMembership tables as a part of our application Models.

I am just curious to know what could be the benefit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you can use users as navigational properties, such as `CreatedByUser`.

Answer (score 1):

It is useful when limited resources are available, for instance, in a shared hosting environment where you only have 1 database available to you.

It also enables navigation properties like CodeCaster said.